# Iterative calculation of $\log x$

Tags: logarithms, approximation

Suppose one is given an initial approximation of $\log x$, $y_0$, so that:
$$y_0 = \log x + \epsilon \approx \log x$$

Here, all that is known about $x$ is that $x>1$. Is there a general method of improving that estimation using only addition & multiplication, i.e. without exponentiation or logarithms?
$$y_1 = f(y_0, x)=\ ?$$

Comment: Without exponentiation or logarithms, it's hard to even tell how close $y_0$ is to $\log x$. This makes me think it will be hard if not impossible to create an iterative algorithm wich doesn't in some form approximate the error $\epsilon$. Taking truncated power series of said functions may or may not count as an answer, though.

Comment: @AlexR - What if you can calculate the integer logarithm, i.e. the nearest integer?

Comment: @nbubis Is $f$ supposed to be a polynomial/rational function?  It isn't clear from your question what "using only addition & multiplication" means: if you can use different operations depending on $x$ then sure, you can compute a Taylor series for $\exp(y_0)$.  If you can't vary the operations based on $x$ then you are effectively restricting $f$ to be a fixed polynomial.

Comment: @ErickWong - I'll expect an answer based on the value of $x$ as long as no addition $\log$'s or exponents are required, other than an integer logarithm.

Comment: @nbubis I'm not sure that answers my question.  Are you saying it would be okay for $f$ to comprise something like "expand the Taylor series for $exp(y)$ to $\lceil x\rceil$ terms, then based on how large it is compared to $x$ add or subtract some expression"?  The $\lceil x \rceil$ value may be overkill but it highlights what I mean by dependence on $x$.  If so then surely you can then use some kind of Newton-Raphson iteration with a suitable approximate exp instead of an exact exp.

Comment: @ErickWong - No. I'm not asking for an accurate value for $\log x$, just one that approximates it better than the current estimate.

Comment: @nbubis I assume "No" means my proposed value of $f$ isn't allowed.  So, what are the restrictions on $f$ then?  Is it a polynomial/rational function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @ErickWong - A rational function of $x,y$, yes.

Answer (score 5):

A long time ago, in the last century, I had an early calculator with no log function.  To do a log, I would hit the square root button ten times, subtract $1$, and multiply by $1,024$.  The answer was good to $4$ decimal places, which was better than my two calibrated sticks could deliver.  Square root is a powerful function that can be used to approximate many others.

Do not ridicule calibrated sticks; they did most of the engineering that got us to the moon!  I recently built a slide rule from Starbucks sticks that does multiplication modulo $23$.  I used logs to base $7$.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of solving $y - \ln(x) = 0$ for $y$ you can solve $g(y) = e^y - x = 0$

Given initial approximation $y_0 \approx \ln(x)$ you can try to solve $y$ using Newton's medhod:

$$y_{n + 1} = y_n - \frac{g(y_n)}{g'(y_n)}= y_n - \frac{e^{y_n} - x}{e^{y_n}} = y_n - 1 +\frac{x}{e^{y_n}}$$

When exponentiation isn't allowed you can approximate $e^{y}$ with $\left(1 + \frac{y}{2^m} \right)^{2^m}$ using repeated multiplication: $$\begin{aligned} \left(1 + \frac{y}{2^m} \right)^{2^m} &= \left(1 + \frac{y}{2^m} \right)^{2^{m - 1}} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{y}{2^m} \right)^{2^{m - 1}} \\ \\2^{-m} &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^{-m + 1}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: You should note that $\left(1 + \frac{y}{n}\right)^n$ isn't very good approximation for $e^y$ when  $y \leq -2n$

Comment: Yes, this is why I asked OP for clarification on what is allowed to go into $f$.  If $n$ has to be chosen based on the size of $y$ then this won't be a rational function of $x,y$.

Comment: @ErickWong If calculations are done on computer with double precision $5 \cdot 10 ^{-324}< x < 2.3 \cdot 10 ^{-324}$ so $\left|y\right| =\left|\ln(x)\right|$ isn't very large.

Answer (score 3):

In any case, you also need to know $x_0=e^{y_0}$.

Then the correction is given by $y-y_0=\ln\left(\dfrac x{x_0}\right)=\ln(1+\delta)$, where $\delta$ is small. You can evaluate it by Taylor which will converge linearly,

$$\ln(1+\delta)\approx\delta-\frac{\delta^2}2+\frac{\delta^3}3\cdots$$

You can also limit yourself to the first term
$$\ln(1+\delta)\approx\delta,$$

but then you will have to correct with $x_1=x_0e^{-\delta}\approx x_0\left(1-\delta+\frac{\delta^2}2\cdots\right)$, which converges a little faster.

I don't think there is a shortcut.

---

A similar approach is given by the CORDIC method.

Precompute a number of decreasing constants $l_k=\log(a_k)$, for instance $a_k=1+2^{-k}$.

You will apply the following steps for all $k$ in turn:

$$\text{while } a_kx_n<x\to x_{n+1}=a_{n+1}x_n, y_{n+1}=y_n+l_k.$$

(If $a_{k+1}>\sqrt{a_k}$, an $\text{if}$ suffices.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that the number you are working with is a floating point number, then the log of it is

$\log( b ) = \log( 2^{\rm exp} * 1.S )$, where exp is the exponent and S is the significand.

$\log( b ) = \text{exp} * \log( 2 ) + \log( 1.S ) $

Since $1.S$ is between 1 and 2, assume it to be 2 then

$\log( b ) ~ (\text{exp} + 1) * \log( 2 )$.

a couple of iterations should give the correct value then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to improve a close guess of the log as you do with square root in Newton-Raphson unless you have the inverse of the log function.  Note that the exponential is easy to evaluate for small arguments because it is a rapidly converging power series.

If you have an exact log of a number z that is close to x, calculate $w=x/z$.   $w$  will be close to 1.  And it is quick and easy to calculate the natural log of numbers close to 1.

Crude: use $\ln(w) = w-1$

Less crude:  $a1 = (1+w)/2$, and approximate $\ln(w) = (w-1)/a1$.  This looks like trapezoidal integration 1 to w of dt/t.  You could do better with Simpson's rule and other numerical integration methods, but that is not where I want to lead you.

Better: $g1 = \sqrt w$, and approximate $\ln(w) = (w-1)/g1$

Continuing, we can get better divisors.  $a2 = (a1+g1)/2, g2 = \sqrt{a2*g1}$, etc.  This does not have quadratic convergence like the Gauss AGM algorithm, but it can be accelerated by the same method used in the HP calculator's Romberg accelerated trapezoidal integrator.  See Carlson, "An Algorithm for Computing Logarithms and Arctangents", Mathematics of Computation, April 1972.  Only a few iterations are needed for very great accuracy. This was taught to me by Nate Grossman of UCLA at a Forth Interest Group meeting way back in the last century.  (Another of his favorite methods was Newton-Raphson on the exponential.)

A lot of our numerical technology involves strategies for avoiding "slow" operations on the computer: multiplication, inverse, square root, etc.  Some day these will be incorporated into hardware and take only a single machine cycle.  New worlds of high-speed computing will open up.  Until then, fast calculation of logs is a core infrastructure of number crunching and a rich field for further exploration.

This is not exactly what you wanted, but I hope it is helpful.